# select * from sheet where column <> 0

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, select

I need an SQL Query statement that selects the rows which has the column O not equal to 0.

example:

```
Col A     Col O
Pencil      1
Ballpen     0
Paper       5
```

I want to put the sheet in a datatable but excluding the rows which has 0 value at the column O. the cells i am selecting starts from row 13 because the excel file still has headers and titles at the first 10 rows.
If i'm not mistaken it would start like:

```
SELECT * FROM SHEET1$ WHERE. . .
```

Comment: You have the correct answer as your question title...  have you not tried anything yourself?

Comment: i have been trying all possible character combinations i can think of, even the one at my question title. None works. :|

Comment: You're using Sql to select data from an Excel spreadsheet?  Which driver are you using for that - can you post some code?

Comment: You should show the code used to connect to the Excel sheet. Also, of uttermost importance is the connectionstring used. (HDR=YES/NO?)

Comment: `code
MyConnection1 = New OleDbConnection _
        ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fname & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""")
                                                                           
MyCommand1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection1)
`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of column O is "O",

`Select * from sheet1$ where O <> 0;`

Column O might have another name, though.

Comment: how do i know the column name? The excel still has a title at row 1, btw.

Comment: the cells i am selecting starts from row 13.

Answer (score 0):

If the Column name O

```
SELECT * 
FROM SHEET1$
WHERE o <> 0 ;
```

Comment: this is actually the same with what xpda answered. sad to say that doesn't work.